# How can an aws lambda know what endpoint called it from API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

If two different endpoints use one lambda, how can the lambda know about the parts of the URL path?

How can one lambda know it was called from `/zips` vs `/zip?zip_code=02140` ?

I can use `event["queryStringParameters"]['zip_Code']` to get the URLs query string - `/zip?zip_code=02140` - from within the lambda,
but how can I know if I am called from the `/zips` endpoint?

I tried using `event["pathStringParameters"]['zips']` which I created a test event for but that didn't work, not recognized.

I can use one lambda per specific resource but I'd like to also know other approaches and how those that use the same endpoint can have their path revealed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am following what you're asking for, namely that you have *one* Lambda function servicing *two* API Gateway endpoints, then I think you have two options:

1. Use the `path` parameter
2. Set a custom header and check that in `headers`

From the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html):

> In Lambda proxy integration, API Gateway maps the entire client request to the input event parameter of the backend Lambda function as follows:

So given this HTTP request:

```
POST /testStage/hello/world?name=me HTTP/1.1
Host: gy415nuibc.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Content-Type: application/json
headerName: headerValue

{
    "a": 1
}
```

You'll have available:

```
  "message": "Hello me!",
  "input": {
    "resource": "/{proxy+}",
    "path": "/hello/world",
    "httpMethod": "POST",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "*/*",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
      ...
```

Here both `path` and `headers` will serve your need.

*Personally*, I would recommend setting a custom header. That way, no matter if your API routing changes, your Lambda will still pick it up.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the path that invoked your Lambda in the `event` object, under `event["requestContext"]["path"]`

You can see more details on what the `event` object contains in the [documentation for using AWS Lambda with API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-on-demand-https.html)

Comment: This is what I try to leave as an answer. :)